Change gradient Values on click / Pressed
The link will show you what I'm trying to achieve
(this is not a real outcome. this video is a concept of my goal)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_MggL4-AMc
I could really do with a helping hand on this lol
(I need to be able to do this for MULTIPULE different gradients individually)
I've tried using Vars with colours and using a Event listener which worked somewhat in codepen with solid colours not gradients but didn't work on my actual site. (this didn't previously work for me.
I have now tried using background images to somewhat success. I'm now trying to figure out how I can go back and fourth with the theme colours as well as set the scale for the background retrieved by the script. (however I'd prefer the original method of changing gradient values on click)
here's a link to the CodePen
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#Background {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  background-image: url("https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/ACUv6h-QQ6PskOhByDXYwHCGjtk1ar3JN5ufhLEEwKxFAJvxxqUyCHMT-DMbK318IVJ_Zn2ustYtg-CcpEPp3egLeHMJoH_teEMKWVjtmw3VSeDvSJpwcqCk89QsDdKjbL4Q9cuPviRrw--RPRXN-uIDTcQYQfkyiQyQT0VMVN5FOwsblLq222dzHRW-YL9huPTGqgmWYNVOc36wpcNva2sVah0UVRLxjeSiGEbF4RPZijO2tp0kYovzRsuybNjkvHbxK4SgO_WGPjebe2Uh9OzoLmygGI-zItBzoqLk9dzLe0Bo6jMQr7v_8fDX3VnJpHNAOMZstzdmXlhQ_INGmlqaaCoTM175t6pYfVxUy_s2qxRotclVumgogKWY2RwUyqk/p.png");
}

  .Embers-Theme-Card {
    --perspective: 1400px;
    --rotateX: 0;
    --rotateY: 0;
    --angle: 6.5deg;
  
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) -20px 20px 20px 0px;
    padding: 2rem;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 2;
    background-image: url("http://localhost:10060/images/Embers.png");
    background-size: cover;
    transform: perspective(var(--perspective)) rotateX(var(--rotateX))
      rotateY(var(--rotateY));
    transition: transform 350ms ease;

    width: 180px;
    height: 75px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    left:800px;
    Top: 100px;
  }
  
  .Embers-Theme-Card > :where(h1, p) {
    background: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.432);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }
  
  .mouse-position-tracker {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
  }
  
  .mouse-position-tracker > div {
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: calc(100% / 3);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-child(1):hover) {
    --rotateX: var(--angle);
    --rotateY: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
  }
  
  .Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-child(2):hover) {
    --rotateX: var(--angle);
  }
  
  .Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-child(3):hover) {
    --rotateX: var(--angle);
    --rotateY: var(--angle);
  }
  
  .Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-child(4):hover) {
    --rotateY: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
  }
  
  .Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-child(6):hover) {
    --rotateY: var(--angle);
  }
  
  .Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-child(7):hover) {
    --rotateX: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
    --rotateY: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
  }
  
  .Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-child(8):hover) {
    --rotateX: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
  }
  
  .Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-child(9):hover) {
    --rotateX: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
    --rotateY: var(--angle);
  }
  
  /* 1st, 4th, 7th */
  .mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-of-type(3n - 2) {
    left: 0;
  }
  /* 2nd, 5th, 8th */
  .mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-of-type(3n - 1) {
    left: calc(100% / 3);
  }
  /* 3rd, 6th, 9th */
  .mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-of-type(3n) {
    right: 0;
  }
  
  /* 1-3 */
  .mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-child(n + 1):nth-child(-n + 3) {
    top: 0;
  }
  
  /* 4-6 */
  .mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-child(n + 4):nth-child(-n + 6) {
    top: calc(100% / 3);
  }
  
  /* 7-9 */
  .mouse-position-tracker > div:nth-child(n + 7):nth-child(-n + 9) {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  
  /* general styling */
  :root {
    --shadow: 0px 1px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02),
      0px 2.5px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.028), 0px 4.6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.035),
      0px 8.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.042), 0px 15.5px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
      0px 37px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  }

  .Embers-Theme-Card
  {
    cursor:pointer;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="Background">
        <div class="Embers-Theme-Card"<button onclick="myFunction()"></button>
  <h1>Embers</h1>


  <div class="mouse-position-tracker">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("Background").style.backgroundImage = "url(https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/ACX0qlkI5_4X1wx38BE5OYUXzWxSZf1IDvUqHhiRXEWE8XbQf6t-OTWScbY8iUOJi1Zw-v0B89055hqh7J87eIpVkC3gfh4ceH5AATuzh95VVChO9wD1TDCYsgQN9Qc6XDWT2p9x3_BG8zhGu6tuaCxreeS_NJDzAa-W3VU38f7L0Ik2lrn-1KI19pu8caW2DkBL1aY7-QePYnjLvaYmGvCrk4ZUYu27ITHJMQYtJd_VsEwCyp3-CLABikGcO0gtaeo1GrhtAjKjC6QRxnmCz3A-uCbb-aF9aJyxkOs3Mues2Pi8H8PNhZ3sZ7pQqbqhChdgg4BvXJPUfeK5RZhWa6jxsXVgYnbTaqEjLWWO7ONvOw/p.png)";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>


In short, you want to create background like the image you provide by css gradient?

@Shuo no, that's something I can already do I've decided to try the image you  linked has been created after.I'm wanting multiple background gradients (now opting for images over css) and have them correspond change on click to the respective theme cards/buttons i created (there is both a video and a codepen)

I am finding hard to understand what you actually wants to accomplish and also cant watch video. Write in proper words so that everyone can understand and help you.

Some issues in your code:
a) <div> around button is not closed.
My idea to do it (jQuery way):
a) Apply the initial CSS to direct body, not with its id. So that you are able to over-write it further.
b) Apply onclick on the parent div directly,and pass its object into function as well.
c) Add a data-class attribute on each parent div and add a corresponding class to it.
d) when the function called, get this data-class value and add it to the <body>.
e) Based on this class either add background-imgae CSS or use gradient Css.
Sample working snippet:


function myFunction(obj) {
  $('body#Background').removeClass().addClass($(obj).data('class'));
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/q78KTSXn/Dark-Mode-Background.png");
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
}

.Embers-Theme-Card-Gradient{
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  position:relative;
}

.Darkmode-Theme-Card-Gradient{
  background-image: linear-gradient(black, green);
  position:relative;
}

.Embers-Theme-Card {
  --perspective: 1400px;
  --rotateX: 0;
  --rotateY: 0;
  --angle: 6.5deg;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) -20px 20px 20px 0px;
  padding: 2rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 2;
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/wBDMSNcj/Embers.png");
  background-size: cover;
  transform: perspective(var(--perspective)) rotateX(var(--rotateX)) rotateY(var(--rotateY));
  transition: transform 350ms ease;
  width: 180px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 100px;
}

.Embers-Theme-Card> :where(h1,
p) {
  background: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.432);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.mouse-position-tracker {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

.mouse-position-tracker>div {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  z-index: 2;
}

.Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(1):hover) {
  --rotateX: var(--angle);
  --rotateY: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
}

.Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(2):hover) {
  --rotateX: var(--angle);
}

.Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(3):hover) {
  --rotateX: var(--angle);
  --rotateY: var(--angle);
}

.Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(4):hover) {
  --rotateY: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
}

.Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(6):hover) {
  --rotateY: var(--angle);
}

.Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(7):hover) {
  --rotateX: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
  --rotateY: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
}

.Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(8):hover) {
  --rotateX: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
}

.Embers-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(9):hover) {
  --rotateX: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
  --rotateY: var(--angle);
}


/* 1st, 4th, 7th */

.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-of-type(3n - 2) {
  left: 0;
}


/* 2nd, 5th, 8th */

.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-of-type(3n - 1) {
  left: calc(100% / 3);
}


/* 3rd, 6th, 9th */

.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-of-type(3n) {
  right: 0;
}


/* 1-3 */

.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+3) {
  top: 0;
}


/* 4-6 */

.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+6) {
  top: calc(100% / 3);
}


/* 7-9 */

.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(n+7):nth-child(-n+9) {
  bottom: 0;
}


/* general styling */

 :root {
  --shadow: 0px 1px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02), 0px 2.5px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.028), 0px 4.6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.035), 0px 8.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.042), 0px 15.5px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0px 37px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

.Embers-Theme-Card {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Background2 {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  background-image: url("https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/ACX0qlkI5_4X1wx38BE5OYUXzWxSZf1IDvUqHhiRXEWE8XbQf6t-OTWScbY8iUOJi1Zw-v0B89055hqh7J87eIpVkC3gfh4ceH5AATuzh95VVChO9wD1TDCYsgQN9Qc6XDWT2p9x3_BG8zhGu6tuaCxreeS_NJDzAa-W3VU38f7L0Ik2lrn-1KI19pu8caW2DkBL1aY7-QePYnjLvaYmGvCrk4ZUYu27ITHJMQYtJd_VsEwCyp3-CLABikGcO0gtaeo1GrhtAjKjC6QRxnmCz3A-uCbb-aF9aJyxkOs3Mues2Pi8H8PNhZ3sZ7pQqbqhChdgg4BvXJPUfeK5RZhWa6jxsXVgYnbTaqEjLWWO7ONvOw/p.png");
}

.Darkmode-Theme-Card {
  --perspective: 1400px;
  --rotateX: 0;
  --rotateY: 0;
  --angle: 5deg;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) -20px 20px 20px 0px;
  padding: 2rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 2;
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/Px4xqk7G/DarkMode.png");
  background-size: cover;
  transform: perspective(var(--perspective)) rotateX(var(--rotateX)) rotateY(var(--rotateY));
  transition: transform 350ms ease;
  width: 180px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 110px;
}

.Darkmode-Theme-Card> :where(h1,
p) {
  background: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.432);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.mouse-position-tracker {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

.mouse-position-tracker>div {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  z-index: 2;
}

.Darkmode-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(1):hover) {
  --rotateX: var(--angle);
  --rotateY: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
}

.Darkmode-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(2):hover) {
  --rotateX: var(--angle);
}

.Darkmode-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(3):hover) {
  --rotateX: var(--angle);
  --rotateY: var(--angle);
}

.Darkmode-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(4):hover) {
  --rotateY: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
}

.Darkmode-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(6):hover) {
  --rotateY: var(--angle);
}

.Darkmode-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(7):hover) {
  --rotateX: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
  --rotateY: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
}

.Darkmode-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(8):hover) {
  --rotateX: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
}

.Darkmode-Theme-Card:has(.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(9):hover) {
  --rotateX: calc(var(--angle) * -1);
  --rotateY: var(--angle);
}


/* 1st, 4th, 7th */

.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-of-type(3n - 2) {
  left: 0;
}


/* 2nd, 5th, 8th */

.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-of-type(3n - 1) {
  left: calc(100% / 3);
}


/* 3rd, 6th, 9th */

.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-of-type(3n) {
  right: 0;
}


/* 1-3 */

.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+3) {
  top: 0;
}


/* 4-6 */

.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+6) {
  top: calc(100% / 3);
}


/* 7-9 */

.mouse-position-tracker>div:nth-child(n+7):nth-child(-n+9) {
  bottom: 0;
}


/* general styling */

 :root {
  --shadow: 0px 1px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02), 0px 2.5px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.028), 0px 4.6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.035), 0px 8.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.042), 0px 15.5px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0px 37px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

.Darkmode-Theme-Card {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#SettingsBox {
  position: relative;
  height: 850px;
  width: 1400px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50px;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 15px #111a;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="Background">
  <div id="SettingsBox">
    <div>

      <div class="Embers-Theme-Card" data-class="Embers-Theme-Card-Gradient" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <h1>Embers</h1>

        <div class="mouse-position-tracker">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="Darkmode-Theme-Card" data-class="Darkmode-Theme-Card-Gradient" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <h1>Darkmode</h1>

        <div class="mouse-position-tracker">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>




Add data-attribute of colors you want to use on btn, then read data-attribute in click event and change css variables.


const changeTheme = ({ currentTarget }) => {
  document.body.style.setProperty("--clr1", currentTarget.dataset.clr1);
  document.body.style.setProperty("--clr2", currentTarget.dataset.clr2);
};
document.querySelectorAll(".theme").forEach((btn) => btn.addEventListener("click", changeTheme));
body {
  height: 100vh;
  --clr1: #4e0000;
  --clr2: #b50000;
}

body {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, black, black 5px, transparent 5px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient(0deg, var(--clr1), var(--clr2));
}
<button class="theme" data-clr1="#4e0000" data-clr2="#b50000">Embers</button>
<button class="theme" data-clr1="#202020" data-clr2="#575757">Darkmode</button>




Thank you Shuo, I've looked it over and taken my time to understand it all, as well as Death-is-the-real-truth's answer allowing me to learn more and understand it so I've taken a lot back from both answers so thank you very much they both work and can achieve what I'm trying to do. honestly thank you for your help.
